# How do I create a prefetch dataset from a folder of images?

Tags: image, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow-datasets, kaggle

I am trying to input a dataset from Kaggle into this [notebook](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cyclegan) from the Tensorflow docs in order to train a CycleGAN model. My current approach is to download the folders into my notebook and loop through the paths of each image and use cv2.imread(path) to add the uint8 image data to a list. But this doesn't work and I know my current approach is wrong because the code provided by google requires a Prefetch dataset.

Here's my current code (excluding the opencv part)

```
import os

# specify the img directory path
art_path = "/content/abstract-art-gallery/Abstract_gallery/Abstract_gallery/" 
land_path = "/content/landscape-pictures/"

def grab_path(folder, i_count=100):
  res = []
  for file in range(i_count):
      if os.listdir(folder)[0].endswith(('.jpg', '.png', 'jpeg')):
          img_path = folder + os.listdir(folder)[0]
          res.append(img_path)
  return res
art_path, land_path = grab_path(art_path), grab_path(land_path)
print(art_path)
print(land_path)
```

The error in the code comes here:

```
train_horses = train_horses.cache().map(
    preprocess_image_train, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).shuffle(
    BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Is there a simpler approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pathlib 
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

@tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
def read_image(path):
   image_string = tf.io.read_file(path)
   image = DataUtils.decode_image(image_string,(image_size))
   return image
    
AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

paths = np.array([x for x in pathlib.Path(IMAGE_PATHS_DIR).rglob('*.jpg')])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((paths.astype(str)))
dataset = dataset.map(self.read_image)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
```